# angularjs - `factory` copy and local copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get all my `allusers` array from `myfactory`:

```
$scope.allusers = myfactory.getFactoryOriginalAllUsers();
///[1,2,3]

$scope.allusers.splice(0,1);
///[2,3]
```

but when I want my original

```
$scope.allusers2 = myfactory.getFactoryOriginalAllUsers();
///[2,3]
```

Why is `$scope.allusers2` the same as `$scope.allusers`? Shouldn't it be still the same as original factory copy which is `[1,2,3]`?

How can I keep the original factory copy untouched?

Answer (score 3):

Objects in js are passed by reference. It means that you return an reference, not entire object (or array).

If you want to modify returned object you must copy it manually.

In your case you should generally copy array:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    newArray.push(array[i]);
}
```

but @bstockwell gives a good advice, that you can use angular method https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: This is correct, but Angular has a copy function that you can use to copy the object as well. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 1):

I am using this two functions:

```
var getType               = (function () {
    var class2type = {},
        toString   = class2type.toString;
    "Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error".split( " " ).forEach( function ( name ) {
        class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
    } );
    return function ( obj ) {
        if ( obj === null ) {
            return obj + "";
        }
        return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ? class2type[ toString.call( obj ) ] || "object" : typeof obj;
    };
})();
/**
 * will copy the object
 * @param obj
 * @param depth
 * @returns {*}
 */
function copyObject( obj, depth ) {
    depth = depth || 0;
    if ( depth < 10 /* max depth */ ) {
        if ( getType( obj ) === "object" ) {
            var deepCopy = {};
            var props    = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj );
            props.forEach( function ( it ) {
                if ( getType( obj[ it ] ) === "object" ) {
                    deepCopy[ it ] = copyObject( obj[ it ], depth + 1 );
                } else if ( getType( obj[ it ] ) === "array" ) {
                    deepCopy[ it ] = [];
                    obj[ it ].forEach( function ( x ) {
                        deepCopy[ it ].push( copyObject( x, depth + 1 ) );
                    } );
                } else {
                    Object.defineProperty( deepCopy, it, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( obj, it ) );
                }
            } );
            return deepCopy;
        }
    }
    return copy( obj );
}
/**
 * copies object and returns new instance without references
 * @param object
 * @param copyProperties
 * @returns object
 */
function copy( object, copyProperties ) {
    if ( object === undefined ) {
        return undefined;
    } else if ( object === null ) {
        return null;
    } else if ( copyProperties ) {

        if ( getType( object ) === "object" ) {
            return copyObject( object );
        } else if ( getType( object ) === "array" ) {
            var list = [];
            object.forEach( function ( it, i ) {
                list[ i ] = copyObject( it );
            } );
            return list;
        }

    } else {
        return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( object ) );
    }
}
```

When you use `return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( object ) );`, you will create a fast copy of the object but will lose definedProperties